# Fitness list replacing elements,optimization

Tags: java

I am working on optimization problem. I am trying to find a key of ciphered text and calculate the fitness each time. If it is better (in this case, bigger) then keep the new key, else stick to the previous one.

I wrote the following, which is not working:

```
if (Fitness.get(i + 1) > Fitness.get(i)) {
    Key.set(i + 1, Key.get(i + 1));
} else {
    Key.set(i + 1, Key.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Can you better describe what you are trying to do here?

Comment: if the next element in Fitness list is smaller than the current one I want to keep the current Key the same, else if it is bigger than the current one I want to update the Key element.

Comment: There is insufficient information in your question to either understand what you are trying to do, or understand the problem that you are experiencing.  Please provide an MCVE: read ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)